# How can i remove the back button from default magento calendar from current date only

Tags: magento-1.9, calendar

How can I remove the Back button from default magento calendar from current date only.

How do you disable the prev button when the previous month is less than the current month?

For instance, if the current month is August, then I want to disable the prev month button so that you cannot see the month of July.

[image]

I successfully disabled previous dates from the calendar.

js Code :

```
var calendarSetupObject = {
                                                    inputField  : "options_'.$optionVal->getId().'_date",
                                                    ifFormat    : "%e/%m/%Y",
                                                    showsTime   : "false",
                                                    align       : "Bl",
                                                    singleClick : true,
                                                    disableFunc: function(date){
                                                        var now= new Date();
                                                        if(date.getFullYear()   <   now.getFullYear())  { return true; }
                                                        if(date.getFullYear()   ==  now.getFullYear())  { if(date.getMonth()    <   now.getMonth()) { return true; } }
                                                        if(date.getMonth()      ==  now.getMonth())     { if(date.getDate()     <   now.getDate() + '.$dod.')  { return true; } } 
                                                        if(date.getDay() == 0) {   return true;   } else {    return false; }
                                                            },


                                                    }
```